# Word to describe policy that attacks the environment?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, terminology

I am putting together a presentation, and for the life of me I am unable to think of the word which describes this situation.

I am discussing policy promoted by the US in Latin America during the 60s which stated that people's land property should be cleared by 80% of natural forest cover to show that it is being utilised.

I am trying to describe how this sort of policy is "hating the environment", has complete disregard, and is driven by capitalism.

Cheers

Comment: these are all great, but I am still on the hunt for that word. I feel as though it is more along the lines/theme of anthropocentrism

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to coin a new word, may I suggest "eco-hostile", by contrast with "eco-friendly".

Comment: It was [coined already](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%22eco-hostile%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=2FA4Va6PJ8yTsAXe_4H4DA#q=%22eco-hostile%22&tbm=bks) and seems quite common. +1

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are most concerned with the lack of thought paid to the environment.

> environmentally negligent

Answer (score 0):

I think you may describe it as an [irresponsible environmental policy](http://www.perc.org/articles/irresponsible-environmental-policy) for the clear negative consequences from an ecological perspective.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll find a single word, at best I can only reword your sentence:

> *Resource depletion sponsored by corporate imperialism* (backed by a stamp that says, *US Gov't*).

This would be a ***right-wing*** government. As those of a left-wing government "believe we should regulate big businesses so they serve people’s interests" and that "country-wide tax-funded action on climate change is necessary." -[idontgetpolitics.co.uk](http://idontgetpolitics.co.uk/right-left-wing)

---

> *non-environmentalist right-wing policy*

E.g., **republican**.

Answer (score -1):

*Conservationist* would describe a policy that conserves natural resources, so you could call it an **anti-conservationist** policy.

Comment: Not my downvote, Nicole, but actually, anti-conservationist sounds more like it's against a person who is a conservationist.  I might opt for an anti-conservation policy instead - but that's just my opinion.